# Define norm as member function of vector class in C++

Tags: c++, vector, std

I'm trying to write my own vector class in C++.In particular, I want to implement the norm as a member function. The following **classic** snippet of code is what I did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
class vector{
private:
    T* elem;
    std::size_t _size;
public:
    vector(const std::size_t size) : elem{new T[size]}, _size{size} {}
    ~vector(){ delete[] elem;}
    std::size_t size() const { return _size;}
    T& operator[](std::size_t i){ return elem[i];}
    const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const{ return elem[i];}
    friend T norm();
};

template <typename T>
T vector::norm(){
    T sum{0};
    for (auto i=0u;i<_size;++i){
        sum+=elem[i];
    }
    return std::sqrt(sum);
}

int main(){
    vector<double> v{10};
    for (auto i=0u;i<v.size();++i){
        v[i] = i;
    }

    std::cout << v.norm() <<std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Clearly, I could define the function `norm` inside the class, but I wanted to define it outside, because in principle the body of one of the member functions may be several lines long.

Once I try to compile, the compiler says that:

- 'template<class T> class vector' used without template arguments
- `_size`, `elem` not declared in scope
- 'class vector<double>' has no member named 'norm'

but I can't understand what's wrong, and how to fix it! In particular, I don't understand the last point: I explicitly declared `norm()` as a member function! How should I change my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring `norm()` as a `friend` function, so it is not actually a member of the `vector` class itself.  You are telling the compiler that some external *non-member* function `T norm()` is a *friend* of `vector` so that it can access `vector`'s private members.  But then you don't actually define such a `T norm()` function!

The correct way to implement `norm()` as a member, with a definition outside of the class declaration, would look like this instead:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class vector{
    ...
public:
    ...
    T norm(); // <-- remove 'friend'!
};

template <typename T>
T vector<T>::norm(){ // <-- note the extra <T>!
    T sum{0};
    for (auto i = 0u; i < _size; ++i){
        sum += elem[i];
    }
    return std::sqrt(sum);
}
```

---

On a side note:

You might consider using [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to omit the declaration+definition of `norm()` for `T` types that `std::sqrt()` does not support (non-integers/floating-point types, like strings, etc).

Also, your `vector` class does not implement the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to manage its inner array properly.  You need to add proper copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators to it.

Comment: I see, thanks! So I can still access member data, i.e. `elem` and `_size`, when I am outside a class, right?

Comment: I just started the introduction to classes, and this is the first part. I tried to add the norm by myself, but I got stucked as you saw :-)

Comment: @Vefhug "*I can still access member data ... when I am outside a class, right?*" - if you properly declare `norm()` as a member, and code its definition with proper syntax so the compiler knows which instantiation of `vector` to look at, then yes, your external definition of `norm()` can access member data of `vector`. "*I just started the introduction to classes*" - which introduction are you using that jumps right into using templates, and splitting declarations from definitions of template members? Those are pretty advanced topics for an introduction to classes to cover.